# aws_encryption_sdk does not return same string on decrypting in python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I am looking to encrypt some secret text using `aws_encryption_sdk`in python .However I see some unwanted character while decrypting. I have used java version of sdk before I did not see any this kind of issue .Below is my code .

```
import aws_encryption_sdk
from aws_encryption_sdk import CommitmentPolicy
import botocore.session
import pytest
import base64

def cycle_string(key_arn, source_plaintext, botocore_session=None):
    
  
    client = aws_encryption_sdk.EncryptionSDKClient(commitment_policy=CommitmentPolicy.REQUIRE_ENCRYPT_REQUIRE_DECRYPT)

    kms_kwargs = dict(key_ids=[key_arn])
    print(kms_kwargs)
    if botocore_session is not None:
        kms_kwargs["botocore_session"] = botocore_session
    master_key_provider = aws_encryption_sdk.StrictAwsKmsMasterKeyProvider(**kms_kwargs)

    # Encrypt the plaintext source data
    ciphertext, encryptor_header = client.encrypt(source=source_plaintext, key_provider=master_key_provider)
    # print(ciphertext, encryptor_header)
    # Decrypt the ciphertext
    encrrtext=base64.b64encode(ciphertext)
    encrciphertext=base64.b64decode(encrrtext)

    cycled_plaintext, decrypted_header = client.decrypt(source=encrciphertext, key_provider=master_key_provider)
    # print(cycled_plaintext, decrypted_header)
    print(encrrtext)
    print(cycled_plaintext)
    print(source_plaintext)

# Verify that the "cycled" (encrypted, then decrypted) plaintext is identical to the source plaintext
    assert cycled_plaintext == source_plaintext

    # Verify that the encryption context used in the decrypt operation includes all key pairs from
    # the encrypt operation. (The SDK can add pairs, so don't require an exact match.)
    #
    # In production, always use a meaningful encryption context. In this sample, we omit the
    # encryption context (no key pairs).
    assert all(
        pair in decrypted_header.encryption_context.items() for pair in encryptor_header.encryption_context.items()
    )

plaintext = "hello there"
cmk_arn = "<arn>"
cycle_string(key_arn=cmk_arn, source_plaintext=plaintext, botocore_session=botocore.session.Session())


    O/P:
b'hello there'
hello there
```

I was expecting it to return same text as source .Any help on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the SDK returns a byte-string. When printing python denotes these by adding the `b''` part. You can convert the byte string to a normal string by adding `cycled_plaintext = cycled_plaintext.decode('UTF-8')` before the assertion.